# Query for Basic information

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

I feel like every second question lacks the basic information about flavour, release and architecture, so I ask myself:

Why don't we just ask the users to give the output of `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`, `lsb_release -d` and `uname -rm` before they submit a question and leave it out just in the rare cases where they are not able to execute these commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the times we need this information is way too small to justify asking from them every time.

If we need that info, we can ask for them in a comment. Maybe it can be added to the [Proforma Comments](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1323/8698) by submitting a pull request on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/askubuntu/ProFormaComments).

Here are two reasons why I think this isn't really needed

1. The thing is, this info is usually used for bug reports, which isn't part of the scope of Ask Ubuntu as those are most of the times closed as off topic.
2. I'm generally against this idea as we need a collection of questions and answers that would help as many people as possible.
   Adding that kind of information can become a hindrance for other people who have the same problem. They may think their problem is different because the person who posted the original question had a different kernel version, a different desktop manager, etc.

As a related note, I'd recommend looking at [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/878/automatically-asking-for-specific-information-based-on-tags-chosen?rq=1). Although there were no responses from SE Staff, it proposes a similar feature. The difference is that the system would ask for a different kind of information based on the tags used.